# Is dockerfile yum using the host yum repos?

Tags: linux, yum, docker

I came across a slow connection when downloading software using yum building a docker image with Dockerfile.

But the yum works well in the host, I was wondering if the yum in Dockerfile using the yum repos configured in Docker host or in the Docker image specified by FROM instruction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're seeing yum called within the Dockerfile. If so, it's executing  within the container and not using yum on the host.

Comment: Thanks. What if I use RUN instead of CMD. It is supposed to be running during the build process. Does the yum still reference the repository in the base image？

Comment: Yes, it would still be isolated to whatever is in the base image. You can try mounting the host yum repo config into the container.